# Can't get NSDate to work correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

having a strange issue, must be something I'm just not seeing.

I set up a variable in the .h

```
NSDate *checkIn;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *checkIn;
```

I'm setting a variable to todays date in the initWithNibName:

```
checkIn = [NSDate date];
```

I also did synthesized it as well. Now later on in my program I use it to build a tablecell with the following line

```
cell.textLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:checkIn];
```

This line kills the simulator, BAD_EXEC. If I put in a checkIn = [NSDate date]; above it, it works fine. So I'm thinking the variable isn't being stored from when I set it in the initWithNibName:

Not sure why though, as my strings I do the same way are all working fine from method to method. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

`checkIn = [NSDate date];`

is a direct assignment and therefore, is released during the autorelease phase.

You want to use your property by making use of dot notation.

`self.checkIn = [NSDate date];`

This is make use of the property attributes (specifically retain) and prevent the date to be released to 0.

Comment: Thank you! This was it. Learn something new everyday. :)